# sitecore compute field not getting called

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-lucene

I have created a custom search config from the   deafult search index configurations

and I have kept `<indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>`,

Also I am created a computed field, which is being called from the config like below

```
<field fieldName="taglist"  returnType="stringCollection">SitecoreComputedField.TaggingItems,SitecoreComputedField</field>
```

Now I have noticed the computed field is not called if I keep `indexAllFields = True` but If I make it false the computed field works like an charm. But I dont want to keep it to `false`. I am not able to find why it is behaving like this ?

Comment: Did you inherit your class TaggingItems from IComputedIndexField?

Comment: Yup @SitecoreClimber

Comment: Which Sitecore version you use? Solr or Lucene?

Comment: Do you have your own custom class for the tagList field?  if so you need to define that where SitecoreComputedField.TaggingItems,SitecoreComputedField is?  Maybe i am missing the question? :).  The storage type = yes suggested below seems sensible but seems odd why it stops working.

Comment: Inherit your computed field from `AbstractComputedIndexField`in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields` namespace instead, and override `ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)` method.

Comment: When you say the computed field is not called, have you tried setting a breakpoint and it does not get hit or that the results are not in the index as you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Index a field will allow you to use that field in a search filter (Eg: by using LINQ or querying directly your index). That is different, however, from actually storing the content of each field at your index (doing that for every fields will highly increase your index size and times).

In your case I think you must force Sitecore to add the value to Index. Try updating your config entry with parameter storageType="YES" so you have:

```
<field fieldName="taglist"  returnType="stringCollection" storageType="YES">SitecoreComputedField.TaggingItems,SitecoreComputedField</field>
```

Comment: It would be important to know your Sitecore version so people can simulate your setup and investigate. I remember to have that working in 7.2

Comment: If your Sitecore is 8.1, there is a very recent issue discovered: a tag <documentOptions> is needed for Sitecore 8.1. Please check: https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/5/t/3307